# In Flask, can I show one template while a function runs and redirect to another once the function is complete?

Tags: python, flask

Basically I want to show a loading page while a time-consuming process takes place and then redirect to my complicated other page.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251898/flask-app-update-progress-bar-while-function-runs

Comment: It depend how long your time-consuming process take, but simple way for relative short wait is to show loading overlay/modal in your template and call directly the page processing the result. Your browser will wait flask response during process and keep showing your loading animation.

Answer (score 7):

While not impossible to achieve, I recommend using javascript for this task.

Here is a small example. First lets write a very simple flask server, with one very slow endpoint.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('redirect.html')

@app.route("/done")
def done():
    return "Done!"

@app.route("/slow")
def slow():
    import time
    time.sleep(5)
    return jsonify("oh so slow")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now, we can make a beautiful user experience by invoking the endpoint from javascript instead. Save it as `templates/redirect.html` as per usual.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function navigate() {
        window.location.href = 'done';  // redirect when done!
      }
      fetch('slow').then(navigate); // load the slow url then navigate
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Loading...  <!-- Display a fancy loading screen -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you explain the expected behavior of your code please.

Comment: If you first read the question, and the my answer in full it should be perfectly clear what it does. If still in doubt, please try to run it! :) Only two files needed. If you have further questions after this, please comment again with a more specific question and I will try to answer.

Comment: Comon man, don't you think I didn't do that. I just don't understand after I ran the same code on my browser i.e. what is the page that is being loaded during the function's run time and what is being show after the completion

Comment: When you load the page the "Loading..." text is show, and then after five seconds you get redirected to a new page that says "Done!".

Comment: It first loads `redirect.html`. On that page, javascript activates that fetches the `/slow` route. Once that is done, it navigates to the `/ done` page.