# Flask - show loading page while another time consuming function is running

Tags: python, html, flask

### Hi everyone. I'm developing my first flask project and I got stuck on the following problem:

##### I have a simple Flask app:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import map_plotting_test as mpt

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def render_the_map():
    mpt.create_map()
    return render_template("map.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

##### Problem

`mpt.create_map()` function here is just making the map, rendering it, then creating the `map.html` file and saving it to the templates folder: `templates/map.html`. It works pretty fine, but it takes some noticeable time to finish making the map (around 10-15 seconds).

The problem is that while this function is performed, I see just a blank screen in the browser, and only then does Flask render the finished `map.html` file.

##### What I want

What I want to do is to show the loading screen instead of a blank screen while the `create_map()` function is running. And when the function finishes its work and creates a map.html file - show rendered template to user just like `return render_template("map.html")` does.

##### Is there a way to achieve this without much effort? I'm new to Flask, and I would be very grateful for a good explanation.

##### Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14525029/15368978)? If so, it might be a good idea to explain why yours is different.

Comment: Sure I've seen it. My question is different because:
1. The app structure is different
2. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14525029/15368978) question requires changes in the base HTML file. As I've said my HTML is generated automatically, I can't edit it.
Sure I can append some sections/tags using [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356014/how-can-i-insert-a-new-tag-into-a-beautifulsoup-object) for further info) but this is not a good workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Finally I found the solution!

> Thanks to [Laurel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402794/18171029). I'll just make it more nice and clear.

##### What I've done

I redesigned my Flask app, so it looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import map_plotting_module as mpm

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def loading():
    return render_template("loading.html")


@app.route('/map')
def show_map():
    return render_template("map.html")


@app.route('/create_map')
def create_map():
    mpm.create_map()
    return "Map created"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When user opens the page, flask stars rendering the `loading.html` file.
In this file you have to add the following code to the `<head>` section:

```
<script>
    function navigate() {
        window.location.href = 'map';  // Redirects user to the /map route when 'create_map' is finished
    }
    fetch('create_map').then(navigate); // Performing 'create_map' and then calls navigate() function, declared above
</script>
```

Then, add a loading wheel div to your `<body>` section:

```
<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
</body>
```

**If it's still not clear for you - please check my example at the end of the answer**

##### Explanation

In the `<script>` section we have to declare `navigate()` function. It just redirects the user to the desired reference, `/map` in the current case.

`fetch()` is the analog to `jQuery.ajax()` - [read more](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). It's just fetching the app route to `/create_map`, awaits it to be done in the "backround", and then performs action in the `.then()` block - `navigate()` function in our case.

**So the workflow is:**

1. User opens the page, `@app.route('/')` function is performed, which is loading page.
2. Loading page fetching `@app.route('/create_map')` and runs its functions in the background.
3. When `create_map()` function is completed - user is being redirected to the `@app.route('/map')` which function is rendering all-done `map.html` template.

##### Few recommendations from me

- If you want your loading page to have an icon, just add the following tab to your `<head>` section of `loading.html`:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="/static/<icon_file>">
```

> **Pay attention**, Flask is searching for media in the `/static` folder. Put your media in it. Otherwise, media will not be rendered!

- If you want your loading page to have a nice CSS loader, consider visiting this page: [loading.io](https://loading.io/css/). I really enjoyed it.

##### Finally, here's code snippet as an example of loader:

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -56px 0 0 -56px;
}

.loader:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #0aa13a transparent #47a90e transparent;
  animation: ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Loading...</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
</body>

</html>
```