# How to show the progress of python script execution statement by statement in real time on browser with Flask framework?

Tags: python, html, flask, websocket

I am trying to convert a command line script written in python in to a web application.

I intend to design a web application using python and flask. The user will provide some input on the webpage and submit it. The input data will then be passed as arguments to a function written in python (basically the old script). This function will be doing a lot of things. As the function is being executed, I would like to show the status of function execution (completed steps) on the web page in real time.

For example - 
If the user enters the values for the fields - `radius, length, breadth, base, height` on the webpage and clicks a `submit` button, a function named `calculate_area(radius, length, breadth, base, height)` will run and the application should periodically send the area for circle, rectangle and triangle one after the other with some time delay between each area calculation. Eg.

```
   Calculating area of circle ...
   Area of circle is - xxx
   Calculating area of rectangle ...
   Area of rectangle is - yyy
   Calculating area of triangle ...
   Area of triangle is - zzz
```

Can someone point me to what can help to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will have to use JavaScript/AJAX to periodically ask server for results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask App: Update progress bar while function runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251898/flask-app-update-progress-bar-while-function-runs)

Comment: Well, instead of a progress bar, it would be nicer if I show the user some status on the webpage.

Comment: @furas - can you please elaborate further or share a link? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@metatoaster pointed you in the right direction: [Flask App: Update progress bar while function runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251898/flask-app-update-progress-bar-while-function-runs)
Instead of returning an integer as progress, you can return a string (e.g. 'Calculating area of circle ...')

On your webpage you'll need to poll for the progress using JavaScript/JQuery/AJAX and append it to a HTML `div` or `textarea` as shown in the example.

```
const logarea = $('#logarea');
setInterval(update_progress, 500); // Polling every 500ms

function update_progress() {
    $.get('progress/' + task_id, function (progress) {    
        if (logarea.val().indexOf(progress) === -1) {
            logarea.val(logarea.val() + progress + '\n');
        }
    });
}
```